# tinker no funciona

Tags: php, laravel

> Php artisan tinker

**al momento de poner ese comando y escribir lo que sea. se sale, CRASH!**

tengo Mac Mojave  - PHP 7.3.6

he hecho esto

lo que dice

[Posible solución](https://medium.com/@yish/laravel-artisan-tinker-psysh-an-valet-can-not-execute-in-php-7-3-c1f6ef442fe7)

al poner esto

```
 vi ~/.config/psysh/config.php
```

Y config

```html
<?php
return [
  'usePcntl' => false,
];
```

no entiendo donde tiene  que ir eso, pues al poner el primer comando

```
 vi ~/.config/psysh/config.php
```

solo me salen todos los comandos que tengo disponibles

Comment: Al parecer necesitas tener un archivo config.php creado en la ruta ./config/psysh  en tu proyecto y colocas el codigo que te estan pidiendo y en caso de existir colocas la llave 'usePcntl' en false

Comment: se me olvido mencionar eso, igual eso hice pero tampoco funcionó

Comment: que es lo que no funcionó? vi es un editor de texto, con el comando `vi ~/.config/psysh/config.php`, lo que haces es abrir el archivo config.php para editarlo, o en caso de que no exista, lo crea al darle guardar. Sesión típica con vi: 
-Escriba `vi file.txt` en el símbolo del sistema
-Mueva el cursor a donde se agregará el nuevo texto
-Escriba `i` para cambiar al modo de inserción
-Escribe un nuevo texto
-Escriba ESC para volver al modo de comando
-escriba `: wq` y ENTER para guardar el archivo y salir

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ eso ya lo hice .... jeje

Comment: Ok, no tengo una Mac Mojave para probarlo, pero la posible solución que propones también es la más aceptada en SO y en el repositorio de tinker en Github para esa cuestión. Pensé que tal vez no estabas encontrando como hacerlo con vi. Nota que es posible que tengas que reiniciar PHP o el sistema al cambiar la configuración. También que la ubicación de ese archivo, no está relacionada con tu proyecto, sino que `~/` se refiere al directorio home, y `~/.config/` a una carpeta oculta en ese directorio